# How can Google Apps Script to share a specific spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created spreadsheets by Google Apps Script, but how can I share them by Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would share the files you have created using the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)

The service has a file method called [setSharing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)

You would need to create a reference to the file/s you have created and then use something like

```
my_file_reference.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

The access permission are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

and

The available permissions are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

Comment: This is my codes which does not work and comes with "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.getFiles. (line 7, file "Code")"                function doGet(e){
  
  var file = e.parameter.account;
//      file = file.toString();
  
  var fileList = DriveApp.getFiles(file);
     while (fileList.hasNext()) {
        var file = fileList.next();
     }
  
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(["Done"]);
   

     }

Comment: The getFiles method doesn't take any arguments so using getFiles(file) is incorrect. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles(). Check your code as if you remove the file argument then the script will get all your files and then only give the last one anyone with the link edit access. Is this what you want? What text are you sending with the ?account=... argument?

Comment: ?account=5 . Actually I created spreadsheet and name it as "1", "2", "3", etc. My purpose is to set "5" spreadsheet to be accessed and as a editor.